# jira-ruby plugin : Pass API Token instead of username and password

Tags: ruby, jira

I am using `jira-ruby` Gem.

```
require 'jira-ruby'

options = {
:username     => 'xxxxxxxx',
:password     => '********',
:site         => 'https://xxx.yyyy.com',
:context_path => '',
:auth_type    => :basic,
:use_ssl => true
}

client = JIRA::Client.new(options)
project = client.Project.find('P-NAME')

project.issues.each do |issue|
  puts "#{issue.id} - #{issue.summary}"
end
```

Here instead of passing the username and password, i want to pass API Token. How can i do that?????

Normal curl command which is working fine is :

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic <TOKEN>" "https://<URL HERE>/rest/api/2/issue/<ID>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct solution I found for this one. Instead I've followed **REST** approach. It will be simple. Atlasssian has good [api documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest).

```
request_payload = {
  body: body, # Body as JSON
  query: params, # URL Parameters
  headers: {
    'Authorization' => "Basic #{auth_token}",
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
  }
}
response = HTTParty.send(:post, url, request_payload)
puts response
```

Please replace `#{auth_token}` with your **API** key. Hope this will help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

So the GEM constructs the basic auth headers. All you need to do is use your Jira email as :username and then the API token as :password. Then it will authenticate.

The Oauth way doesn't work with Jira Cloud REST API. Only Jira Server is compatible.

Comment: Oauth way is working with my solution. While moving from gem to REST API only, I got this error. But I've to check on using token as password itself. Thanks for info though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the documentation really unclear in this aspect. Here is what worked for me so far:

```
options = {
  :site             => 'https://my.jira.site',
  :context_path     => '/my_jira_path',
  :auth_type        => :oauth,
  :consumer_key     => 'jira_consumer_key_name',
  :consumer_secret  => 'jira_consumer_key_secret',
  :access_token     => 'jira_oauth_access_token',
  :access_secret    => 'jira_oauth_access_secret',
  :private_key_file => 'path/to/private_key_file',
}
```

In my case I had manually pre-authorized my app with Jira via oauth authentication, because this is a script that doesn't enable for a callback to obtain the token auth back, therefore I used the `access_token` and `access_secret` obtained this way.

After creating the client with `JIRA::Client.new(options)` I had to also set the token manually (this might not be necessary if you are able to get the callback, but I haven't explored that way):

```
client.set_access_token(options[:access_token],options[:access_secret])
```

Hope this works for you too.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But no direct solution using API Token. So instead of using this ruby gem, I've now moved to make direct rest url requests. :)

Comment: So what is the API token? Can you make an example on how you make those direct rest requests?

Comment: I've posted the solution. Please check.